# Keep sending messages in Spring Integration

Tags: spring-integration, poller

One module sends messages to the message broker every N second. The other module receive the messages from the broker. The messages is built in a method sendMessage of the service activator. The plan was to use inbound channel adapter (as in the answer) but for some reasons this solution does not work and I keep receiving "Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'". What is wrong with this configuration?

```
<int-jms:inbound-channel-adapter id="keepAlivePoller" channel="keepAliveChannel" destination="keepAlive" connection-factory="connectionFactory"> 
        <si:poller id="sendPoller"  fixed-rate="${keepalive.sendinterval}" max-messages-per-poll="1"></si:poller>
    </int-jms:inbound-channel-adapter>

    <si:service-activator input-channel="keepAliveChannel" method="sendMessage" ref="keepAliveSender"/>
    <bean class="com.foo.KeepAliveSender"/>

    <si:channel id="keepAliveChannel"/>
```

Comment: Can you show those ' some reasons this solution does not work' ?

Comment: Sure :) I keep getting [PollingConsumer] [AbstractTransactionSynchronizingPollingEndpoint.java] [DEBUG] [task-scheduler-1] Received no Message during the poll, returning 'false'[PollingConsumer]  every N sec.

Answer (score 0):

That will only send a message if there is a message in the "keepAlive" queue.

You can simply use...

```
<int:inbound-channel-adapter id="keepAlivePoller" channel="keepAliveChannel"
        expression="'foo'"> 
    <si:poller id="sendPoller"  fixed-rate="${keepalive.sendinterval}" />
</int:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

... and not use JMS at all.

Comment: This solution actually works. I need to use JMS because a separate module sends the messages to the ActiveMQ broker and another one receives them.

Comment: Right, but it will only "work" if there is actually a message in the `keepAlive` queue. You will keep getting `Received no message...` until one exists.

Comment: I sort it out with Spring scheduler. Thank you for your feedback.